# ShareThis not display properly when initially hidden

Tags: jquery, hide, sharethis

How to make ShareThis buttons show correctly after clicking the 'show' button? After I push the 'show' button, all '.st-btn' has 'display:none' until I resize the window and it becomes 'display:inline-block' automatically... In other words, the ShareThis display properly only after I pushed the 'show' button and resize the window manually. Thank you in advance

```js
$('span').hide();
$('button').click(function(){$('span').show();});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=58ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03357&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>

<button>show</button>
<span><div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons"></div></span>
```

[sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/1mygfzr2/)

Answer (score 5):

In order to solve your issue it's enough to change from:

```
$('span').show();
```

to:

```
$('span').find(':hidden').addBack().show();
```

Show span element plus all the hidden elements under it.

The code ([jsfiddle here)](https://jsfiddle.net/t8Lq9ay2/1/):

```js
$('span').hide();
$('button').click(function () {
    $('span').find(':hidden').addBack().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=58ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03357&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>


<button>show</button>

<span><div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons"></div></span>
```

Comment: This 1 is not perfect for this solution would show buttons that should be hidden based on other criteria. For example, an SMS button should be stay hidden on non-mobile devices. My example was the only 1 found online that is suitable for my application, unfortunately this example didn't contain SMS button...